# Write .ods openoffice / libreoffice files in R

Tags: r

There are many ways to read .ods packages in R, e.g. with gnumeric packages. But I can't find any way to *write* an .ods file directly.  Any ideas?

(This would be particularly useful because google drive spreadsheets appear as .ods files locally, so it would be a way to edit google spreadsheets without using solutions like RGoogleDocs which won't work offline.)

Comment: Looks like you're going to be stuck writing a .xls file and either converting externally or writing a macro (callable via tools like `XLConnect` to do the conversions indirectly from `R`

Comment: Thanks, pity. Funny, I thought there would be more demand for this as, like I said, it is a good way to update published google spreadsheets from R.

Comment: There may have been no solution when the question was written. At  this time, the package `readODS`  can write ods files.

Comment: @G5W Can you write an answer? Otherwise this will be listed as "unanswered".

Comment: @user3293236   will do.

Answer (score 17):

This question is old. I am just filling it in so that it will not be unanswered.  There may have been no solution when the question was written. At this time, the package readODS has a function `write_ods` that will write an ods file.  Quick example:

```
library(readODS)
write_ods(iris, "iris.ods")
```